# Delete record using entity framework

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework-6

I am having trouble deleting an entity -

```
Using db As Context = New Context
        Dim car = db.Car.First(Function(x) x.ID = txtCarID.text)
        db.Entry(car).State = Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted
End Using
```

I have tried many other syntax, here is another -

```
 Using db As Context = New Context
        Dim car = new Car With {.ID = txtCarID.text}
        db.Car.Attach(car)
        db.Car.Remove(car)
End Using
```

I have received no errors but the record is never deleted.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `SaveChanges` method of `DbContext` after you made the changes. Otherwise changes will not be committed to databse.

Comment: Wow... I knew that too but never connected the dots. Thank you for the quick reply, it is much appreciated!